# Mobile keyboard open delay

Tags: javascript

I have an question i cant find any answer for it. How long is the delay till your mobile keyboard opens? Is it possible to detect if your keyboard is fully opened? Usually when the mobile keyboards opens up it slides from the bottom upwards and thats the delay i am talking about.

Comment: are you looking for a number? e.g. 200ms?

Comment: yes, or an way to detect if the keyboard is fully opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyboard is handled (opening, closing) by OS, so you have no control over that; by the way javascript has its own keyboard interface [navigator.keyboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard) which gives you a limited control on that. in the time of writing there is **no** **way** to **determine** if the keyboard is open/close, and timing varies from OS to OS;

But there is a interesting peace of information in [keyboard ui controller](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/55f44515cd0b9e7739b434d1c62f4b7e321cd530/ash/keyboard/ui/keyboard_ui_controller.cc) of chromium mobile repository in github where the `WILL_HIDE` duration ( transition between `SHOWN` to `HIDE` ) is `100ms` and in my opinion is pretty close to what we see in a andriod phone.

Comment: Thank you. I have an chat that is needed to scroll to the bottom whenever somebody open his keyboard. I have putted 200ms so it should be ok i guess